# I can run assembleDebug to completion, but not assembleRelease

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, release

I'm having a weird issue that appears to be app-specific as I can't reproduce on any of my other projects.

What's happening is that when I go to build a release version of the app and sign it Android Studio just stalls on "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" in the Event log. The "Gradle Build Running" indicator flashes for about 10 seconds, but then disappears. If I try to build something else (like a regular debug version), or clean the project, I get the dialog box saying "Generate Signed APK | APK(s) generated successfully" but when I go to the folder the release APK is nowhere to be found.

I've tried cleaning, building, updating Android Studio (and all plugins, etc.) but I still have the same issue.

I've tried creating new Keystores with new keys, but I can't get past "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" in the Event log.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, but the issue persists which leads me to believe that I'm overlooking something specifically in the app itself.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's start with the simple potential causes: Did you set the keystore name, alias name, and password in Android Studio?

Comment: Post your build.gradle and run gradlew assembleRelease in the terminal to get the final log

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip from Gabriele Mariotti I found that  my issue was in the build.gradle and had to do with lintOptions.

Adding:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

to the Android subsection of my build.gradle resolved my issue